# Need to remove two quoted from value searching by key

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to remove Quotes which is appearing in the value of json using its key using regex, the data itself has quote where as in json also coming with quotes, where in which it throws error Unexpected token s in JSON

```
"{"segerity": 5,"someData": ""AB3EncKrodPvc"", "segerity": 2}"
```

I am trying like this

```
 const quoteRemove = quoteReplace.replace(/someData["]+/g, '');
```

Expected result

```
"{"segerity": 5,"someData": "AB3EncKrodPvc", "segerity": 2}"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can replace two or more consecutive `"` with single `"` using [**replace**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

```
/"{2,}/
```

```js
let str = `{"segerity": 5,"someData": ""AB3EncKrodPvc"", "segerity": 2}`

let op = str.replace(/"{2,}/g, '"')

console.log('string -->', op)
console.log('Object --->', JSON.parse(op))
```

Comment: @MaheerAli  Thanks, `+` means one or more and replacing `"` again with `"` it just overhead

Comment: That makes sense